# how to replace part of string using re.sub in python

Tags: python, expression

I have:

```
desVar ("vrgt1" "0")
```

so I used:

```
re.sub(r'"vrgt0".+"(.+)"', '"a"',line)
```

And I got :

```
desVar( "a" )
```

But I what I want is:

```
desVar( "vrgt0" "a")
```

Is that any method only replace part of the matched using `()`?

Comment: please edit and correct your formatting to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed string, why don't you just add it afterwads?

```
re.sub(r'"vrgt0".+".+"', '"vrgt0" "a"',line)
```

You could maybe use named groups:

```
re.sub(r'(?P<name>"vrgt0".+)"(.+)"','\g<name>"a"', line)
```

Examples:

```
print re.sub(r'(?P<name>"vrgt\d*".+)"(.+)"','\g<name>"a"', '"vrgt1" asd "0"')
> "vrgt1" asd "a"

print re.sub(r'(?P<name>"vrgt\d*".+)"(.+)"','\g<name>"a"', '"vrgt151"   "1231"')
>"vrgt151"   "a"

print re.sub(r'(?P<name>"vrgt\d*".+)"(.+)"','\g<name>"a"', '"vrgt"   "0-abc"')
> "vrgt"   "a"

print re.sub(r'(?P<name>"vrgt\d*".+)"(.+)"','\g<name>"a"', '"vrgt918" -- "0"')
> "vrgt918" -- "a"
```

Comment: Hi tglaria, the examples are great.